# Pfsense networking, routing and rules

Tags: pfsense, dhcp-server

I'm new to pfsense I just installed it today. I'm trying to configure a DHCP server. I have three interfaces the WAN, LAN and Guest Network. I configure the LAN to 192.168.0.1/20 and the WAN is DHCP address and the guest network is set 172.16.0.1/22 in the LAN side and this where the DHCP server running.
I can ping in the LAN side but not in the Guest Network. My DHCP is getting a good IP from the DHCP pool but not getting internet. that the problem.

I don't know if I misconfigure or something lacking.

Comment: Most likely, you did misconfigure something.  however, we can't tell what that is unless you edit your question to include your pfSense config.  Use the preformatted test option { }.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Firewall rules for the guest network. You may also want to create a rule to block access from the Guest network to the LAN network or any other you want to restrict from the guest.

[image]